# Need to include the sum of participation

Tags: java, math, random, sum

I am using Math.random to include participation of students from a group (separate class). I successfully created the output, but now need to know how to show the sum of participation of students within the group.

```
public class student {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String participation;

    student(String a, String b, String p) {
        firstName = a;
        lastName = b;
        participation = p;
    }

    String getName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + participation;
    }

    String whatsUp() {
        double r;
        int myNumber;
        String participation = "";
        r = Math.random();
        myNumber = (int) (r * 3.0) + 1;

        switch (myNumber) {
            case 1:
                participation = "participation is " + Math.floor((Math.random()
                        * 10) + 1);
                break;
            case 2:
                participation = "participation is " + Math.floor((Math.random()
                        * 10) + 1);
                break;
            case 3:
                participation = "participation is " + Math.floor((Math.random()
                        * 10) + 1);
                break;
        }

        return participation;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you have a constructor that takes a value for participation if you construct the actual return value in the `whatsUp()` method?

Comment: @user583345 What do you mean by sum of participation? Your participation is in String.

Comment: Could you write the output that you currently have and the output that you expect to receive?

Comment: John's participation is 9.0
Mike's participation is 6.0
Trevor's participation is 40
Phil's participation is 8.0 //need the sum of these numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make participation an `int` and return the string from it's own method.

```
public class Student  {
    String firstName; 
    String lastName; 
    int participation; 

    Student (String a, String b) { 
        firstName = a; 
        lastName = b; 
        participation = (int) Math.floor((Math.random()
                    * 10) + 1); 
    } 

    String getName() { 
        return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + whatsUp(); 
    } 

    int getParticipation() {
        return participation;
    }

    String whatsUp() {
        return "participation is " + participation;
    }
}
```

To sum participation for all your students, iterate them and call `getParticipation()` from them:

```
int sumParticipation = 0;
for (Student s : students) {
    sumParticipation += s.getParticipation();

}
```

To print their individual participation, call `whatsUp()`.

BTW, the class has some serious problems. In Java, class names should be capitalized (`Student`), and what's worse, in the `whatsUp()`-Method there's a switch block that does the same for each case - I have eradicated it

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the data structure that holds the students, for example an `Array` of students. You can print the sum of participation of the students by changing the `participation` variable to an Integer type and assign the random generated number to it.